# cakephp email component emails go to hotmail junk folder

Tags: email, cakephp, components, spam, hotmail

I am using the built-in email component of CakePHP 1.3, and it seems that all my emails go to the hotmail junk folder. 
Does any of you know what to change to make Hotmail thinking this is NOT a spam? If some of you experienced the same issue, some feedback on what they've done or tried to fix it would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake simply uses the PHP built-in mail() facility. Without any further setup your mail is not going to be delivered by a proper MX server but rather the sendmail binary connects directly to the SMTP port on the remote host and attempts to deliver.

You see how easy it is to set up a spam sending facility like this. Mails delivered by a random machine instead of a proper mail server are very likely to be classified as spam.

Ask the web server admin to set up mail sending from the server. Alternatively you could use any trusted SMTP server to send mail (e.g. google).

Comment: Hi sibidida, I am the administrator of our dedicated server. Are you asking me to use a SMTP connection instead of the PHP mail() feature? Why shouldn't I be able to use the php function without sending all the emails into the hotmail junk folder? Cheers,

Comment: Mail is always delivered by SMTP. But it makes a difference who is the connecting party. By default for example mail() will introduce itself as a random machine (EHELO localhost). Looking at this mail servers check for example whether it has a proper MX record in DNS. If they think you are not a real mail server you get a higher spamscore. This has nothing to do with PHP: anybody can and many spammers really send spam like this, and mail servers are classifying like this for good. I'm asking you to configure PHP or your own SMTP server that it looks for hotmail as a legitimate one.

Comment: Okay, I understood what you meant. I will have a look at my MX records and try to find some tutorial somewhere to configure PHP with my SMTP. I'll keep this topic updated. Cheers,